# How to join two tables with MySQL and display data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to join two tables and assign a task from the "tasks" table to a user in the "users" table.

My tables and columns are:

```
tasks: 
task_id,
task_description,
userid

users: 
user_id,
first_name,
last_name

<?php 

$join_query = "
SELECT task_id
     , task_description
     , tasks.userid
     , users.user_id
     , first_name
     , last_name
  FROM tasks
  JOIN users 
    ON tasks.userid = users.user_id
";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $join_query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $name = $row['first_name'];
    $description = $row['task_description'];

}

?>
```

The table join seems to be working as I can echo the data with different aliases. But I'm trying to make it possible to assign tasks to users. Am I even close? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Assigning a task to a user means setting the userid field in the tasks table to a valid user id. This has got nothing to do with join or select. This is either an insert or an update. Pls clarify your question!

Comment: Ok great. Thanks! I will regroup and try to solve it a different way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First look at your query and change it to this.

```
$join_query = "
SELECT tasks.*
     , users.*
  FROM tasks
  INNER JOIN users 
    ON tasks.userid = users.user_id
";
```

Then fetch an associative array of the data:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $name = $row['first_name'];
    $description = $row['task_description'];

}
```

As you were selecting all fields of both table so * will do this for you. And when making a join it is good approach to use the table name with field name. And in the fetch an associative array to get results. Everything else is fine :)

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try this and see if it works. I really appreciate it. :)